# Layer writing / exporting time in QGIS takes far too long

Tags: qgis, export, csv, performance

I am finding that QGIS takes quite some time when writing or exporting large datasets (approx 5 million records). A task I'm currently doing requires me to export 5 million points to a CSV, and this is taking some 20 minutes.

Writing a layer of 4 million lines took about an hour. These times seem somewhat outrageous. Copying the data (OS level) only takes about 40 seconds.

I've seen others write about slow I/O times.

Is this a known issue, an area that requires work?

Comment: Writing/exporting is not the same as just copygin (OS level), I suppose...? Technically, it involves more procedures in my understanding to **create** a file than to just **copy** it.

Comment: What format is the data you're exporting?  Shapefile?  Database table? ?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details. I just exported 5 million points and it took 25 seconds.  Please edit your question and include details about your data (number & type of columns, spatial reference), how you are exporting and whether you are reprojecting/changing the CRS, where you are writing the CSV to (HDD/SSD, local/network/cloud drive).

Comment: Excellent comments and sorry for not providing more information. 
There is no reprojection applied. 
The point data is quite simple, 5 attributes of INT and STRING
I'm outputing the data to a CSV (yes, no geometry required). Definitely takes longer than 20 seconds to do 5 million points writing to an SSD / USB 3.1.  Anyone can do this test generating random points using the Vector menu.